# 4 Element abelian subgroup of S5.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutations

I have a homework question from my intro to group theory class.

Question:

Find a 4 element abelian subgroup of $S_5$.  Write it's table.

This is where I've gotten so far, but I don't even know if I'm on the right mental track.

We know $S_5 = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
Abelian means the subgroup of $S_5$ is commutative.

I am having trouble figuring out how to start this.  Do I pick any 4 elements of $S_5$?  Or are there particular elements that must be chosen?

Do I perform permutations on the group first?
Or do I chose my 4 elements, and then perform the permutations?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to find a subgroup of $S_5$ which has four elements and is abelian. (One of the) Hint:Can you find a such a subgroup in $S_4$?

Comment: You should double check your definition of $S_5$.

Comment: Abeliannes of the subgroup is not to be checked as it comes for free: all groups of order four are abelian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$S_5 \neq \{1, \,2,\, 3,\, 4, \,5\}$, but rather, $S_5$ is the *group of permutations* of the 5 elements in $\{1,\, 2,\, 3,\, 4,\, 5\}.$

Hint: Pick an abelian subgroup of order $4$ (hence not just **any** *four elements*, but four elements in $S_4$ that together meet the criteria of a commutative *subgroup* of $S_5$.)

Such a group can easily be found by choosing a permutation, call it $\sigma$, of *order $4$,* and then determining the cyclic subgroup $H$ of $S_5$ that is generated by $\sigma$: $\;\; H =\{id,\, \sigma,\, \sigma^2, \,\sigma 3\}$. And so we have a cyclic, and therefore abelian, subgroup $H$ of $S_5$.

**Additional hint**: Let $\sigma$ be a $4$-cycle in $S_5$ (A $4$-cycle is cycle of length $4)$.

Take, for example, the $4$-cycle $\sigma = (1\,2\,3\,4)(5) = (1\,2\,3\,4)\in S_5.\,$ Then $\,\sigma^2 = (1\,3)(2\,4) \in S_5,\,$ and $\,\sigma^3 = (1\,4\,3\,2)\in S_5.\,$ Finally, $\sigma^4 = id$. Hence we have that $\langle \sigma\rangle = \{\sigma, \sigma^2\, \sigma^3, id\}$ is a cyclic (hence commutative) subgroup of order $4$ in $S_5$.

Comment: I recently started studying group theory so please forgive my ignorance. You said "Such a group can easily be found by choosing a permutation, call it σ, of order 4". My question is: how do you find a permutation of order 4 in the first place? For example, how did you knew that σ=(1,2,3,4) was 4-cycle in S5?

Comment: @amb110395 $\;\;S_5$ contains *all* permutations on 5 numbers. $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ (where $5$ is held fixed) is one such permutation. The order of a cycle is equal to its length,  so $\sigma$ has order 4.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was not aware that the order of a cycle is equal to its length. That answers everything. Thank you!